# C++ regex match content inside curly braces

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, std

Suppose I would like to do extract the contents of matching curly braces using C++11 regex. So, for example, `{foo}` would match successfully and I could the use the `match_result` to extract the contents. It seems simple, but the following code does not quite do what I wish

```
std::string foo("{foo}");
std::regex r("\\{(.*)\\}");
std::smatch m;
bool result = regex_match(foo, m, r); // result returns true

cout << m[0] << endl; // prints: {foo}
cout << m[1] << endl; // prints: {foo} instead of just foo as I would expect
```

Now shouldn't `m[1]` return just `foo` without the braces given that it is the first capture group?

**EDIT:** An essential piece of information for this question is that the compiler I'm using is GCC 4.6.3 (which currently is the latest repository version in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). The answer identifies precisely how poor the support for regex in GCC is.

Comment: Note if you are a gcc user, mostly all of the regex stuff is not implemented yet.

Comment: Compiler/standard library? Most of compilers/standard libraries, including gcc/libstdc++ had not fully implemented regex support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is correct. Your code is largely correct with few missing 'std'' here and there (for 'cout', 'endl' and regex_match), or at least inconsistent (assuming you are 'using namespace std').

Moreover, on Visual Studio 2012, your code output the expected result. I didn't try 2010, but I suspect it is running there as well (Microsoft incorporated TR1 back in 2010).

I suspect you are using gcc. As @Artyom pointed out, in gcc/libstdc++ isn't implemented. It compiles fine with no warnings but it gives the wrong results. Despite the common belief that gcc is superior than Microsoft in every area, this isn't the case in regular expression.

Find status of regex on gcc here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Comment: You're absolutely correct. GCC still has poor support for `std::regex`. It's unfortunate that everything would compile without errors given that this is the case. I guess I need to switch to boost for regex for now.

Comment: Microsoft added TR1 in 2008, as a feature-pack precursor to VC++ 2008 SP1 (then incorporated into said service pack).

Comment: 5 years layer g++ v4.8 is the default g++ version on Ubuntu 14 which has Long Term Support for years to come.  And, apparently, regex compiles but doesn't work.  Argh.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/2950621 for more about limitations of  v4.8 regex support.