# QRegEx to highlight everything between braces

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm trying to get a regular expression to match the text between curly braces

[The following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets). Gave me a start but it's not working for me. And I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Consider the following:

```
The {quick} brown fox {jumped over the} lazy old {dog}. While {the [0ld] man} spoke {to the} gardener.
```

What I am trying to do is to match all the text between the curly braces, so I can highlight them. The expression

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

did not work for me. I'm not sure why.
I'm using python 2.10/pyqt, and the QRegExp class of pyqt on Windows.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong.

Just to add more detail, this time with some code. consider the following

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MyHighlighter( QSyntaxHighlighter ):

    def __init__( self, parent, theme ):

        QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__( self, parent )
        self.parent = parent
        keyword = QTextCharFormat()


        self.highlightingRules = []

        # keyword
        brush = QBrush( Qt.darkBlue, Qt.SolidPattern )
        keyword.setForeground( brush )
        keyword.setFontWeight( QFont.Bold )
        keywords = QStringList( [ "break", "else", "for", "if", "in", 
                                  "next", "repeat", "return", "switch", 
                                  "try", "while" ] )
        for word in keywords:

            pattern = QRegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")
            rule = HighlightingRule( pattern, keyword )
            self.highlightingRules.append( rule )


        # braces
        singlebraces = QTextCharFormat()
        pattern = QRegExp( "\{(.*?)\}" )
        pattern.setMinimal( False )
        brush = QBrush( Qt.darkRed, Qt.SolidPattern )
        singlebraces.setForeground( brush )
        rule = HighlightingRule( pattern, singlebraces )
        self.highlightingRules.append( rule )

    def highlightBlock( self, text ):

        for rule in self.highlightingRules:

            expression = QRegExp( rule.pattern )
            index = expression.indexIn( text )
            while index >= 0:
                length = expression.matchedLength()
                self.setFormat( index, length, rule.format )
                index = text.indexOf( expression, index + length )
            self.setCurrentBlockState( 0 )

class HighlightingRule():

    def __init__( self, pattern, format ):

        self.pattern = pattern
        self.format = format

class TestApp( QMainWindow ):

    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily( "Courier" )
        font.setFixedPitch( True )
        font.setPointSize( 10 )
        editor = QTextEdit()
        editor.setFont( font )
        highlighter = MyHighlighter( editor, "Classic" )
        self.setCentralWidget( editor )
        self.setWindowTitle( "Syntax Highlighter" )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    window = TestApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Well when i run this and type anything between curly braces, it does not get highlighted red. Just for good measure I have left the keywords in to show that the code does do syntax highlighting.

Note: 
I did try the expression `\{(.*?)\}` on the website and yes it did work, but not clear why the expression isn't working in the code.

Comment: Ho it doesn't works for you? what's wring with `>>> re.findall(r'\{(.+?)\}',s)
['quick', 'jumped over the', 'dog', 'the [0ld] man', 'to the']
`

Comment: Your regex works... You can check here https://regex101.com/r/kV5dR1/1 If you still have problem post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227802/c-regex-match-content-inside-curly-braces) questions seems to have the answer, at least one that works for me. The expression

```
"\\{(.*)\\}"
```

Seems to do the trick. But I would like to know WHY. My knowlege of regex can be written in entirely, double spaced on the back of a napkin. Any additional clarification would help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`setMinimal(true)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qregexp.html#setMinimal):

> **QRegExp.setMinimal (self, bool minimal)**
>
> Enables or disables minimal matching. If minimal is false, matching is greedy (maximal) which is the default.

Thus, the code will look like:

```
QRegExp rx("\\{(.*)}"); 
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the following is working for me:

```
string = 'The {quick} brown fox {jumped over the} lazy old {dog}. While {the [0ld] man} spoke {to the} gardener.'

import re

ans = re.findall(r'{.*?}', string)
```

As pointed out by @Alan Moore, I was wrong about the `re` matching the unescaped parenthesis, still you don't need the scape sequences if you you raw string notation `r'string'`.

Comment: *I'm using python 2.10/pyqt, and the QRegExp class of pyqt on Windows.* Your answer does not solve the issue in the original question.

Comment: I don't know about `pyqt`, but this answer is definitely wrong for Python's `re` module.  It may not be *necessary* to escape the braces in this regex, but it's not incorrect to do so.  And unescaped parentheses are metacharacters; they will *not* be matched literally.