# std::regex_replace gives me unexpected result

Tags: c++, regex, windows, c++11

I'm using `std::regex_replace` in a C++ Windows project (Visual Studio 2010). The code looks like this:

```
std::string str("http://www.wikipedia.org/");
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^@:/]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::string fmt("https://$1wik$2.org/");
std::string result = std::regex_replace(str, fromRegex, fmt);
```

I would expect `result` to be `"https://www.wikipedia.org/"`, but I get `"https://www.wikipedia.wikipedia.org/"`.

A quick check with `sed` gives me the expected result

```
$ cat > test.txt
http://www.wikipedia.org/
$ sed 's/http:\/\/([^@:\/]+\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\.org\//https:\/\/$1wik$2.org\//' test.txt
http://www.wikipedia.org/
```

I don't get where the difference comes from. I checked the flags that can be used with `std::regex_replace`, I didn't see one that would help in this case.

**Update**

These variants work fine:

```
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^@:/]+\\.)wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::regex fromRegex("http://((?:[^@:/]+\\.)?)wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::regex fromRegex("http://([a-z]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^a]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

bu not these:

```
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^1-9]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^@]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
std::regex fromRegex("http://([^:]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

It makes no sense to me...

Comment: What compiler are you using? If it's GCC give up: `<regex>` *is not implemented*. Use boost instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware that any compiler had regex support yet. Is this a recent update to a compiler?

Comment: @sftrabbit MSVC's STL has had a functional regex implementation since version 2008, and LLVM/Clang's libc++ has a complete regex implementation as well.

Comment: @rubenvb I clearly didn't research very well.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, why is that? Is boost's version so different that they couldn't just plug it in and call it a day?

Comment: @Mark here's an explanation, straight from the horse's mouth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/46642

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes pretty decent explanation, but it doesn't explain two things: a) why are they running behind on all the competition? and b) why don't they just plug in Boost.Regex? But you're not the one I should be asking this, obviously, though I fear Jonathan won't like me pressing the issue `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

There's a subtle error in the regular expression. Don't forget that escape sequences in string literals are expanded by the compiler. So change

```
"http://([^@:/]+\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\.org/"
```

to

```
"http://([^@:/]+\\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\\.org/"
```

That is, replace each of the two single backslashes with a pair of backslashes.

EDIT: this doesn't seem to affect the problem, though. On the two implementations I tried (Microsoft and clang), the original problem doesn't occur, with our without the doubled backslashes. (Without, you get compiler warnings about an invalid escape sequence, but the resulting `.` wildcard matches the `.` character in the target sequence, just as a `\.` would)

Comment: Or change it to use raw literals - which help with the leaning toothpick problem: R"http://([^@:/]+\.)?wik(ipedia|imedia)\.org/".  Note the preceding R.

Comment: @emsr - sure, if you have a C++11 compiler that supports raw literals.