# C++ TR1 Regular Expressions Not Available

Tags: c++, regex, namespaces, g++, tr1

I'm trying to utilize the 'TR1' regular expression extensions for some C++ string parsing. 
I've read that the `<regex>` header and namespace std::tr1 are required for this

I can compile with the `<regex>` header present(though it forces me to use either the flag,     `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`)

However, when I attempt to use the `std::tr1` namespace in my program, compiling fails with message that tr1 "is not a namespace name". I cant do things like,

`std::tr1::regex rx("mypattern");`

I've read that TR1 regular expressions have been supported since gcc 4.3.0. I'm using g++ through gcc 4.4.5.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Regexes aren't implemented in GCC.

Comment: @nhahtdh No, it isn’t. The classes are largely empty stubs.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `regex` has been moved from `tr1` to `std` in C++11.

Comment: @nhahtdh no, the algorithms and stuff don't work.

Comment: @nhahtdh *sigh*. No, it’s not. Like I said, [the classes are largely empty stubs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/1968).

Comment: Man, there's a lot of serious misinformation out there then. Is there a comparably simple alternative regexp library that is gnu-friendly?

Comment: You could have a look at the boost version.

Comment: I'm having a look. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[g++ 4.7 doesn't implement regular expressions yet.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)**

But despite that fact, in C++11 `regex` has been moved from the namespace `std::tr1` to `std`. So, instead of `std::tr1::regex`, you should write `std::regex`:

```
std::regex rx("mypattern");
```

I don't know for which g++ versions before 4.7 this applies, too. But [this ideone example](http://ideone.com/1yWpbh) compiles fine with g++ 4.7. However, remember that the regex implementation isn't implemented in this compiler version.

Comment: It is still a largely empty implementation in G++.

Comment: Yeah, it compiles but doesn't do hardly anything.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, I'll add this. Didn't know and just did a quick check and didn't notice that.

Comment: I feel uneasy about the fact that there is `<regex>` but unimplemented. It compiles but behaves as nonsense. Pretty dangerous if you don't know that.

Comment: @leemes - welcome to the world of free software. You get what you pay for.

Comment: It's not "dangerous" unless you write code and don't bother testing it, in which case it's you that's dangerous, not the C++ implementation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/981959 for why a header is shipped with an incomplete implementation