# Regex C Help on escape character

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am having trouble extracting the token values from  my string : *"JOIN  #ROOM\r\n"*
I am compiling my code on Mingw64 with the following arguments : *g++ tregex.cpp -o tregex.exe -std=gnu++11*

I get this error , but not my exception for some reason :

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
>     what():  regex_error

This is my code :

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Tregex.cpp

int main(void) {
    regex rgx("[[:cntrl:]]");
    string str = "JOIN  #ROOM\r\n";
    smatch match;
    try{
        if(regex_search(str, match, rgx))
            for(auto token:match) cout << token <<"\n";
        cout<< endl;
    }
    catch(regex_error & e){
        if( e.code() == regex_constants::error_escape )
            cerr << "invalid escape character \n";
        else if( e.code() == regex_constants::error_stack )
            cerr << "regular expression is not big enough\n";
        else
            cerr << "exception caught: "<< e.what()<<"\n";
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<regex>` support in gcc is [far from complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408). You should switch over to using Boost if you need regex.

Comment: is `[[:cntrl:]]` supported in C++11 regex?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that regex was still in crude form for gcc. So, is the visual studio compiler for windows fully implemented? I'll stick with using boost then.

Comment: @HeroofCode Visual Studio 2012 does support regex, but it is lacking several other C++11 language features.

Comment: @Praetorian -- Isn't regex TR1 (circa 2003)?

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Regular_expressions)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there's nothing wrong with your C++ code, and it works perfectly using Clang and [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org) on my MacBook.

As indicated by the comments above, `<regex>` is one of the features that works in the LLVM project's libc++ but [has never worked properly in the GNU project's libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408). You might try switching to libc++ if it's available for your platform.