# C++ regex_match behaviour

Tags: c++, regex, stl

I am using C++ regex. was not able to grasp the following programming output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  regex r("a(b+)(c+)d");    
  string s ="abcd";
  smatch m; 
  cout << s << endl;
  const bool b = regex_match(s,m, r);
  cout << b <<endl; // prints 1 - OK
  if(b){
    cout << m[0] << endl; // prints abcd - OK 
    cout << m[1] << endl; // prints ab - Why? Should it be just b?
    cout<<  m[2] << endl; // prints bc - Why? Should it be just c?
  }

}
```

I per my exposure to regex in other languages, the parenthesis should match the captured part of the string? so the output should be

```
1
abcd
b
c
```

EDIT:
I  am using g++ 4.6

Comment: Can't reproduce. My copy of VC2010 prints 'b' and 'c', as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce using g++ 4.7

Comment: @Igor i used g++ 4.6 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using g++, you should note that [its implementation of `<regex>` (section 28) is incomplete](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x).  Note the listings for `basic_regex`, `sub_match`, and `match_results` are declared "Partial".

For more info on g++, I think [this post from a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408) is still relevant (as is [this bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631)).

This would explain why it's not giving the results that you expect.  You may wish to try Boost regex in the meantime.