# Why does regex block on replace?

Tags: c++, regex

why does this piece of C++ code block forever?

```
string word = " a\n";
regex indent("^( |\t)*");
word = regex_replace(word, indent, "");
```

and why does this piece of C++ code terminate quickly?

```
string word = " a\n";
regex indent("^( |\t)+");
word = regex_replace(word, indent, "");
```

and to add one more twist why does this terminate quickly?

```
string word = " a\n";
regex indent("^( |\t)+?");
word = regex_replace(word, indent, "");
```

I would expect that `"^( |\t)+?"` would be the same as `"^( |\t)*"`

I am using libc++ and llvm and the standard c++ regex library.

Comment: Last I heard libstdc++'s `<regex>` is not complete. [See this answer to a related question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/445976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine. The regex library is mostly not implemented in your version of libc++. Your best bet is to use another library like boost or an updated version of libc++.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that `^( |\t)*` matches nothing (i.e. the * means 0 or more so it matches one space, one tab, or the empty string) and the existing (bad) algorithm find a lot of nothing in the input string... forever. In other words, you hit a bug in that regex implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and compiled the bleeding edge version of libc++ and the `"^( |\t)*"` version no longer blocks. So I am going to chalk this up to an old library.