# std::regex - C++ Linux undefined reference link errors

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11

I have been researching this all afternoon. I need to use regex on an embedded Linux project. It is not possible to use boost. I compile but run into linker errors - undefined references to the regex functions. I have tried adding the -std=c++11 option to the compiler command, and have tried using the #include without success. Can anyone tell me if there is a library, option or setting to try to get a regex program to build?

The answers I have seen so far seem to suggest that regex is only partly implemented. Can anyone tell me if this is true and what parts have been implemented?

Thanks in advance

John Babrick

Comment: I have also tried upgrading to GCC 4.8.1. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and Eclipse.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/525217).

Comment: GCC will support regular expressions Real Soon Now. They said so!

Comment: OK< thanks. I did try and search this out. I have never needed to do regex programming before. Thanks for the link, I needed a definitive answer.

Comment: Are you linking against the boost regex libraries? Do you see `/usr/lib64/libboost_regex-gcc48-mt-1_53.so` or `-lboost_regex` or similar in your linker command line?

Comment: regex is only in 4.9.0 which is not released yet. Check out the head and have fun! The patch is still hot from this week!