# C++ std::regex implementation in different compilers

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11, gcc4.7

Consider the following code.

```
std::regex re ("(qwe|asd|zxc)+");
std::cout << std::regex_match ("zxcqweasd", re) << std::endl;
```

When I use the `cl` compiler program prints `1` and `0` if I use the `g++` compiler.

Which `std::regex` implementation is wrong?

I'm using `g++` compiler version 4.7.2-5 and `cl` compiler version 17.00.60610.1.

Comment: g++ regex is not implemented fully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait `g++ 4.9`

Comment: @clcto - "not implemented fully" - I suppose, in marketing talk. "Implemented only as useless stubs" is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

gcc 4.7 has not complete standard library support for c++11. Regex is the main part missing.

cl compiler is correct.