# C++ Regex Runtime error

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying C++ regex first time, and I use example minimized from cplusplus.com, but I have runtime error always..

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main () {

    std::string s = "there is a subsequence in the string\n";
    std::string e = "$1 and $2";
    std::cout << regex_replace(s, std::regex("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)"), e);

    return 0;
}
```

COMPILE:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -c C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test.cpp -o C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test.o
mingw32-g++.exe -o C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test.exe C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\test.o
```

ERROR:

[image: Runtime Error]

Answer: [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408) @R. Martinho Fernandes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408

Comment: thanks :) I only have 1 little question. How can they run [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_replace/) this code then?:D Another version of gcc?

Comment: Are you sure they ran it? They could just be showing what the output should be in a working implementation. Or they might use a different compiler, like MSVC or clang with libc++.

Comment: Good point :) Thanks for fast answer :)