# Strange results when using C++11 regexp with gcc 4.8.2 (but works with Boost regexp)

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, c++11, gcc4.8

I tried to use C++11's regular expression but failed even in trivial examples. From the outside, it seems to only compare the strings, for example:

```
std::regex_match(std::string{""}, std::regex{"a?"})   // false (???)
std::regex_match(std::string{"a?"}, std::regex{"a?"}) // true  (???)
```

In contrast, the Boost's regexp library behaves as I would have expected:

```
boost::regex_match(std::string{""}, boost::regex{"a?"})   // true  (OK)
boost::regex_match(std::string{"a?"}, boost::regex{"a?"}) // false (OK)
```

I tested with GCC 4.8.2 and clang 3.4 (also using GCC's STL library). Either the library is broken, or I do not understand the syntax defined by the C++11 standard.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org - GCC's regex support is very new.

Comment: I guess the problem is in grammer.

Comment: clang with [its own library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) gives true, then false, same as boost.regex. GCC 4.8.2 does not support regex, you need 4.9.

Comment: GCC prior to 4.9 supports `<regex>` syntactically but not semantically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported in GCC 4.8.x.  Check out the corresponding Bugzilla entry:

> http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631

Specifically:  "Now regex is implemented. Should come with GCC 4.9 :)"

Comment: Why does 4.8.x compile regexes successfully silently, driving me half to insanity rather than throwing an error or warning?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions) for why