# how can I parse url query string by C++?

Tags: c++, node.js, http

Is there a light-weight library for this?

I'm use node.js to parse url log file, but I found it's slow by it's default module `querystring` and tj's `qs`.

So I wonder if there is a C++ library to parse the url (better to json string directly) and it's light-weight enough to compile to a node C++ addon.

```
qs.parse('/?0=foo')
qs.parse('/?a[>=]=23')
qs.parse('/?foo=bar&baz')
qs.parse('/?a[b][c]=d')
qs.parse('/?a[b][c][d]=e')
qs.parse('/?a=b&a=c')
qs.parse('/?a[]=b')
qs.parse('/?a[]=b&a[]=c&a[]=d')
qs.parse('/?a=b&a[]=c')
qs.parse('/?a[]=b&a=c')
qs.parse('/?a=b&a[0]=c')
qs.parse('/?a=b&a[1]=c')
qs.parse('/?a[b][]=c&a[b][]=d')
qs.parse('/?a[1]=c&a[0]=b&a[2]=d')
qs.parse('/?a[1]=c&a[0]=b')
qs.parse('/?a[20]=a')
qs.parse('/?a[12b]=c')
qs.parse('/?he%3Dllo=th%3Dere')
qs.parse('/?a[b]=c%20d')
qs.parse('/?foo[0]=bar&foo[bad]=baz')
qs.parse('/?foo[bad]=baz&foo[0]=bar')
qs.parse('/?foo[]=bar&foo[bad]=baz')
qs.parse('/?foo[0][a]=a&foo[0][b]=b&foo[1][a]=aa&foo[1][b]=bb')
qs.parse('/?a[]=b&a[t]=u&a[hasOwnProperty]=c')
qs.parse('/?foo[0].baz=bar&fool.bad=baz')
// ...
```

well, can you feel my problem?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268236/parse-http-request-without-using-regexp/28269049#28269049

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thx @Galik , do you know array and object type url param? Such as "foo[bar]=baz", "a[0]=b&a[1]=&a[2]=c" etc..

Comment: @RoryJaffe  Which book, tool, software library, tutorial do you mean? I'm green in C++, it's better if you can give some, well, even one keyword for my problem, thanks.

Comment: So, do you want to parse in JS and then passing the result into a native module or directly in C++?

Comment: @JasonWihardja  node's http module get the http headers such as : "/?foo[bad]=baz&foo[0]=bar", and using C++ to parse it into json string, like { "foo": { "bad": "baz", "0": "bar"  } }, and return to node.js.  This produce is slow by js.

Comment: What about something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63181227/2193968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) library and in particular the URI class (boost::network::http::uri). More information [here](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/in_depth/uri.html).

Comment: Francesco, Thanks a lot~