# Parse URL "query" part

Tags: c++, http, httprequest, rfc, url-parsing

In https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1 with reference to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4 described uri format. And in particular the "query" part

> The query component is indicated by the first question    mark ("?")
> character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character    or by the
> end of the URI.

But question mark ("?") can be a part of path as well and i can not find any notes for parsing this in rfc. Is there any standart way to do it? Or finding question mark ("?") and trimming  string until sign ("#") character or its end is right way (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269049/13214408))?

Comment: "can be a part of path" no it cannot. `?` is a reserved character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"?" starts the query part in any URI (not only http(s)).

If you need a "?" in the path, you'll need to percent-escape it.