# Problems with regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2012

I want to match following string but receive always false and match is empty. Only if the expression is equal to the string the return value is true. My regex seems to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   regex rgx("use_gui=((true|false)); state=((bla|blub|blob))");
   cmatch cm;
   string s("use_gui=false; state=bla");
   bool ret = regex_match(s.c_str(), cm, rgx);

}
```

Comment: See this if you're using gcc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/873025

Comment: It matches for me with G++ 4.8.1 locally and at ideone: ideone.com/2zIz4u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider removing the extra parenthesis:

```
regex rgx("use_gui=(true|false); state=(bla|blub|blob)");
```

This [fixed it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a4bd301f781599a) for me. (Thanks @Lightness Races in Orbit for showing me coliru)

Comment: I didn't say the code is not correct. I don't match the string.

Comment: Well, he does have more () than necessary (but that shouldn't prevent the match).

Comment: It matches [almost correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a63b9a6c02362da5) but there _is_ something up

Comment: I just ran the code in Visual Studio 2012. It also matches for me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, am I right in thinking it executes perfectly on your coliru link?

Comment: @OGHaza: No, as I just said, there is still something up. The `=` shouldn't be part of the matches. But it _does_ match so the OP is seeing something else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ah right, I couldn't see what was up before

Comment: @alex555: Not in the code you showed us, you didn't. Are you saying you posted a question that did not reflect the code you were _actually_ running? What a waste of our time :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's not. Before posting I had a `\s` in the middle of the regex string. I admit, that the code is not exactly the same, but usually `\s` is a blank, `use_gui=(true|false);\sstate=(bla|blub|blob)` returns false

Comment: This is why it's important to post _exactly_ the code that produced a failure in your environment. :-(

Comment: @alex555: Well that is completely different!

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written matches correctly for me and matches the string.  I recommend not using the double parentheses, which are not necessary and may be confusing the regex engine that you're using:

```
int main()
{
   regex rgx("use_gui=(true|false); state=(bla|blub|blob)");
   cmatch cm;
   string s("use_gui=false; state=bla");
   bool ret = regex_match(s.c_str(), cm, rgx);
   cout << "matches: " << cm.size() << endl;
   for (cmatch::iterator p = cm.begin(); p != cm.end(); ++p) {
     cout << "match: " << *p << endl;
   }
}
```

On my machine (OSX 10.9, XCode) this produces:

```
matches: 3
match: use_gui=false; state=bla
match: false
match: bla
```

Comment: `for (auto p : cm) cout << "match: " << p << '\n';` is all you need!

Comment: Ooh, that's lovely, thanks. (My C++ experience comes mostly from pre-C++11, so I'm still catching up to all of this newfangled `auto` stuff  you kids are using.)

Comment: I am not an `auto` fanboy by _any_ stretch of the imagination, but to me this is one of the rare GOOD uses. :-)

Answer (score 1):

So your regex is basically valid, despite the superfluous capture groups. There must be something you're not showing us.

Unfortunately, [in GCC 4.8 you get a `=` at the start of each match](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a63b9a6c02362da5), but [regexes are fixed properly in GCC 4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/873025).