# C++ std::regex track 2

Tags: c++, regex

I want to extract track 2 data from a string, using `std::regex` in C++.
I have a piece of code, but it does not work. This is the code:

```
std::string buff("this is ateststring;5581123456781323=160710212423468?hjks");
std::regex e (";\d{0,19}=\d{7}\w*\?", std::regex_constants::basic);
if(std::regex_match(buff, e))
                    {
                       cout << "Found!";
                    }
```

Comment: What is "track 2 data"? Also, you need to escape your slashes. The string parser gets them before the regex engine does...

Answer (score 0):

From the [regex_match documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/):

> The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this function to return `true` (i.e., without any additional characters before or after the match). For a function that returns `true` when the match is only part of the sequence, see [regex_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/).

So try using `regex_search` instead:

```
std::regex e (";\\d{0,19}=\\d{7}\\w*\\?", std::regex_constants::basic);
if(std::regex_search(buff, e))
                {
                   cout << "Found!";
                }
```

Comment: Not working. `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.`

Comment: `std::regex_constants::basic` does not seems to support `\d` or `\w`. Try `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript` (the default).

Comment: i used "std::regex_constants::ECMAScript", but i got the same error

Comment: Here's some more useful information, if you're using G++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions.  TL;DR: std::regex doesn't work in GCC prior to version 4.9.