# Matching single digit with std::regex_match

Tags: c++, regex

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/), I should be able to match a single digit with

```
std::regex e1 ("\\d");
```

However, when I run the following test code I get a regex exception.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::regex r("\\d");
  std::string s("9");
  if (std::regex_match(s, r)) { std::cout << "matched!" << std::endl; }
}
```

Comment: If it's any consolation, it works great on my box with VC++2013. You should be able to catch an `std::exception` and use its `what()` method to get more info.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Platform, compiler? (Oh, and probably you're just being punished for `abusing namespace std;`...)

Comment: I'll fix namespace and then update.  I'm running on debian with gcc.  Compiling as: g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

Comment: GCC won't have regex support until 4.9.

Comment: then why does it compile?  And it will match if I do: std::regex r("9");

Comment: Perhaps your library is the updated version with regex implemented. Before, it would just silently return false from `regex_match`.

Comment: gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
Perhaps I need to try upgrading my compiler.  I'm also seeing using mingw in Windows (where I first ran into this).

Comment: just reproduced the described behavior (runtime exception on line 7) on 4.8 - e.what() just states `regex_exception`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC's `std::regex` support is not yet ready for prime time. See: [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

If std::regex support is still buggy as @qwrrty suggests, the character class `'[0-9]'` is a substitute for `'\d'`.

Comment: I tried writing some very simple C++ code to answer another GCC-related `std::regex` question a few days ago. It threw exceptions even on very simple regexes like `[0-9]`. I would not recommend even trying to use GCC 4.7 for any regex work whatsoever.