# How to get length of regex match with C++11 or Boost?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++11

Is there a library function which can be used to get length of the first regular expression match (and if there is no match it returns 0)?

So i need some function principialy similar to this:

```
int length_of_match(const std::string& s, const std::string& rx)
{
    ...
}
```

Which can be easily used for example this way:

```
int a = length_of_match("number = 10", "^[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*");
int b = length_of_match(" = 10", "^[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*");
```

and after that `a == 6` and `b == 0`

?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for replies, that helped me lot. Solution for my question is:

```
int length_of_match(const std::string& s, const std::string& rx)
{
    boost::regex expr(rx);
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
    if (!regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), what, expr)) return 0;
    return what.length();
}
```

Boost works great. I tried also STL regex, but i find that STL regex functionality is buggy with mingw GCC 4.7.1:

[is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Comment: You may get *length* of *result* match of `std::regex_match`

Comment: virtually all regex search facilities will give you the matching substring if you want it (eg instead of a yes/no for match present). You can then ask the length of that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [match_results](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html) boost documentation, there is: `length(n)` which returns the length of the specified match.

An alternative approach would be: get the matched `string` and return its length.