# Problems with grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I need to parse an expression and I'm using boost :: spirit, the expression must have the form 
(@anything but @ followed of the string .PV@), 
and I am using the following grammar

```
P = S >> "." >> V;

S = ch_p('@') >> +~ch_p('@');

V = str_p(".PV@");
```

but does not work me, could you tell me where is the error. I need do it with a grammar and I am using namespace boost::spirit

Comment: You're using ancient SpiritV1. Please move to SpiritV2. Also, your description is very very confusing. Can you give a SSCCE with expected input/outputs?

Comment: What is your use case?  This sounds like something you could do with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** For completeness adding the regex approach (see at the bottom)

In spirit V2 I'd suggest the simpler

```
    P = S >> V;
    S = '@' >> +(char_ - '@' - V);
    V = ".PV@";
```

Assuming that you didn't mean a double `.` to be required. See a test program **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e8f8ddc96f59261)**.

Also, note the `confix` parser in the spirit repository, which could do this slightly more succinctly:

```
confix('@', ".PV@")[+(char_ - '@' - ".PV@")]
```

See that **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37093d967fd3ba91)** as well.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_confix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using boost::spirit::repository::confix;

int main()
{
    std::string const input("@anything but &at; followed of the string .PV@");
    std::string parsed;

    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
    bool ok = qi::parse(
            f, l,
            confix('@', ".PV@") [+(qi::char_ - '@' - ".PV@")],
            parsed);

    if (ok)   std::cout << "parse success\ndata: " << parsed           << "\n";
    else      std::cerr << "parse failed: '"       << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    if (f!=l) std::cerr << "trailing unparsed: '"  << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";

    return ok? 0 : 255;
}
```

Output:

```
parse success
data: anything but &at; followed of the string
```

---

### Regex Approach

Depending on your use case, you could use a regular expression as has been pointed out in comments. See a simple demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b590b47dde47cd)**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using boost::regex;

int main()
{
    std::string const input("@anything but &at; followed of the string .PV@");

    boost::smatch matches;
    if(regex_search(input, matches, regex("@(.*?)\\.PV@")))
        std::cout << "Parse success, match string: '" << matches[1] << "'\n";
}
```

Bear in mind,

- Boost Regex is *not* header only, so you incur the library dependency if you don't already use it
- `std::regex` is *not* ready on any compiler/platform I know of

Comment: Added the [regex approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4b590b47dde47cd) for the sake of completeness

Comment: I believe GCC 4.8.2 libstdc++ now has a regex implementation, libc++ has had it since forever, and MSVC also had it since at least VS2008 (in tr1 back then), and in `std` since 2010? How is it not ready? (I haven't used any of these myself for anything, I just know of their existence)

Comment: @rubenvb Last time I checked they all "appeared" to have `<regex>`, but it was utterly broken. Now, I haven't included libc++ there. Also, this is quite widespread knowledge, so I'm pretty sure I can't be far off. Then again, perhaps recent versions all of a sudden came up with the goods, but chances are the OP isn't using them, so the fair warning stands.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/85371) (with a handsome +50 votes) mentions that GCC 4.9 will ship with working `std::regex`. It's unknown when this will be released http://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline