# Problems boost spirit is deprecated

Tags: boost-spirit

I have the following grammar:

```
#include <boost/spirit.hpp>

struct point_grammar
: public boost::spirit::grammar<point_grammar>
{
   template <typename Scanner>
   struct definition
   {
      boost::spirit::rule<Scanner> E, S, V;

      definition(const point_grammar &self)
      {
         using namespace boost::spirit;
         E = S >> V;
         S = '@' >> +(~ch_p('@') - V);
         V = str_p(".PV@") | str_p(".CV@");
      }

      const boost::spirit::rule<Scanner> &start()
                  {
         return E;
                  }
   };
};
```

When I compile, the compiler show me the following warning:

> /usr/include/boost/spirit.hpp:18:4: warning: "This header is
>   deprecated. Please use: boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp"

But when change the #include for boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp, I have the following error:

> (expected template-name before ‘<’ token) in the line where is: :
>   public boost::spirit::grammar.

What I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

You *should* upgrade to Spirit V2. I actually showed you how to do this in "[Problems with grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365433/problems-with-grammar/21368892#21368892)" :)
*Seriously. Boost 1_36 was released August 14th 2008*.

Now, the docs (http://boost-spirit.com/home/doc/) explain

> To avoid namespace conflicts with the new Spirit V2 library we moved Spirit Classic into the namespace `boost::spirit::classic`. All references to the former namespace boost::spirit need to be adjusted as soon as the header names are corrected as described above. As an alternative you can define the preprocessor constant `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_OLD_NAMESPACE`, which will force the Spirit Classic code to be in the namespace `boost::spirit` as before. This is not recommended, though, as it may result in naming clashes.

*(source page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new.html under "Classic")*

So, you *could* continue using the same code if you update the namespace references.