# How do I create a case insensitive regex to match file extensions?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to match all files that have the extension `.nef` - The match must be case insensitive.

```
regex e("(.*)(\\.NEF)",ECMAScript|icase);
...
if (regex_match ( fn1, e )){
    //Do Something
}
```

here `fn1` is a string with a file name.

However, this "does something" only with files with `.NEF` (upper case) extensions. `.nef` extensions are ignored.

I also tried -

```
regex e("(.*)(\\.[Nn][Ee][Ff])");
```

and

```
regex e("(.*)(\\.[N|n][E|e][F|f])");
```

both of which resulted in a runtime error.

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
>   what():  regex_error
> Aborted (core dumped)
> ```

My code is compiled using -

```
g++ nefread.cpp -o nefread -lraw_r -lpthread -pthread -std=c++11 -O3
```

What am I doing wrong? This is my basic code. I want to extend it to match more file extensions `.nef`, `.raw`, `.cr2` etc.

Comment: That exception probably doesn't have anything do with your regex string, but it's because you're using gcc's regex implementation, which is broken. gcc will ship with a working `<regex>` in version 4.9

Comment: Why do you try to match "." with "\\."? Shouldn't it be "\."?

Comment: @Praetorian - Oh! So some of these http://cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf will not work??

Comment: @l19 - The first ` \ ` (c++) is to escape the second ` \ ` (regex) which is to escape the ` . `.

Comment: [`^(.*)(\.)([Nn][Ee][Ff])$`](http://rubular.com/r/XxHenYdwwS) seems to work correctly. though you should escape the `'\'` as you already know, and includes the extension as a separate capture group (which can be convenient). If this doesn't work on your end you're regex has issues. What regex are you using anyway?

Comment: @WhozCraig - I am using the standard regex (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) and that expression did not match any file :-(

Answer (score 5):

Your original expression is correct, and should produce the desired result. The problem is with the gcc implementation of `<regex>`, which is broken. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/241631) explains the historical reasons why it so, and also says that gcc4.9 will ship with a working `<regex>` implementation.

Your code works using [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Simple regular expression matching
    boost::regex expr(R"((.*)\.(nef))", boost::regex_constants::ECMAScript |
                                        boost::regex_constants::icase);
    //                ^^^           ^^
    // no need escape the '\' if you use raw string literals
    boost::cmatch m;

    for (auto const& fname : {"foo.nef", "bar.NeF", "baz.NEF"}) {
        if(boost::regex_match(fname, m, expr)) {
            std::cout << "matched: " << m[0] << '\n';
            std::cout << "         " << m[1] << '\n';
            std::cout << "         " << m[2] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/828e943ef295e2ce)

Comment: Thank you. I think I shall use the boost implementation the next time I code. For now, I have used `regex e("(.*)(\\.)(((N|n)(E|e)(F|f))|((C|c)(R|r)2))",ECMAScript|icase);` - the `icase` is useless. to match `.nef` and `.cr2` the way I want it.

Comment: That should work, but you really don't need that horrendous looking expression if you use the `icase` flag. `regex expr(R"dlm((.*)\.(nef|cr2))dlm", ECMAScript|icase);` will get you the same result.