# std::regex_replace does not take fewer than 6 arguments

Tags: c++, regex, linux, c++11, std

I'm trying to learn how to use the regex library in c++11.
On ubuntu 13.10 I'm trying to compile the following example from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_replace/):

```
// regex_replace example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"

  // using string/c-string (3) version:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"sub-$2");

  // using range/c-string (6) version:
  std::string result;
  std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), s.begin(), s.end(), e, "$2");
  std::cout << result;

  // with flags:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$1 and $2",std::regex_constants::format_no_copy);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

With the command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o file file.cc
```

I get the following output:

```
file.cc:13:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_replace(std::string&, std::regex&, const char [7])’
```

What am I doing wrong?! There's not much hair left on my head...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of gcc and libstdc++ are you using?

Comment: Works with clang++/libc++ http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e52aacb4bb121c9c

Comment: I'm using libstdc++6.

Comment: What does `g++ --version` print? GCC did not support C++11 regular expressions until [version 4.9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408)

Comment: version 4.8.1 ... That explains a lot. Version 4.9 seems to be under development, or can I update gcc to that version?

Comment: @Niklas: Yes, it's under development, but it's really close to release so you could update to a trunk build in the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[You need to update your compiler from GCC 4.8 to GCC 4.9.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/560648)**

Unfortunately, GCC 4.9 has not been released yet, but it's stable enough to go with a trunk build if you need this functionality imminently.

Alternatively, give Clang or [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) a go.

Comment: boost.regex could be a viable alternative, too

Comment: @Cubbi: This is true.