# std::regex not matching a working expression?

Tags: c++, regex

For whatever reason, the regexp I made for my program will not match to lines that match in any other implementation. I'm wondering if there's some new syntax I'm not understanding?

Here's my own implementation:

```
std::string line, pattern("[LS] 0x[0-9a-fA-F]{8}");
std::regex rx(pattern, std::regex::basic);
uint line_count = 0;

while (getline(in_file, line))
{
    line_count++;

    if (std::regex_match(line, rx))
    {
        bool type = (line[0] == 'L');
        uint address = (uint) std::stoul(line.substr(4, 8), nullptr, 16);

        m_type_store.push_back(type);
        m_address_store.push_back(address);
    } else {
        std::cerr << line << " |" << line_count << '|' << std::endl;
        in_file.close();
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And every time it cannot match the first line of the file, which is exactly:

```
S 0x0022f5b4
```

And that looks completely fine to me... Am I missing something?

Comment: Please notice: g++ broken implementation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions

Comment: My only suggestions for improvement would be to provide a complete main function that others can copy and paste easily.  Also what implementations are you comparing to?  You also haven't stated what compiler you are using.

Comment: I tried that regex with the Faust Regex explorer addin for visual studio.  The expression worked fine for me except that you have not anchored it with '^'.  Perhaps that was by design.  I tested a sample program with GCC 4.7.2 and it did not work, so if you are using GCC then the link above is probably the answer.  http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: @DieterLücking just for the record, `libstdc++ 4.8` is equally buggy. OTOH, 4.9 brought us working `<regex>`. But who has access only to `gcc <= 4.8` or does not has access to `libc++` has to resort to `boost::regex` instead...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using *Basic* regular expression. I'm not sure about C++, but normally in Basic RE, you need to prefix the `{` and `}` with a `\` when specifying multiplicity. In other words, your code should be:

```
std::string line, pattern("[LS] 0x[0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}");
```

Alternatively, you can use *Extended RE* instead of *Basic RE*, as in `std::regex::extended`.

Comment: Sorry, no, it did not solve my problem. It seems that regex is broken for g++ as mentioned by Dieter.