# regex("(abc|aa.*|bb.*)") Vs regex("(aa.*|bb.*|cc.*)");

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I encounter a weird problem when using regex in c++11 (ubuntu 14.4 ,gcc 4.8.2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    regex r("(abc|aa.*|bb.*)");
    cout<<regex_match("bb11",r)<<endl;  //return false
    cout<<regex_match("aa11",r)<<endl;  //return true
    cout<<regex_match("abc",r)<<endl;   //return true
    return 0;
}
```

while

```
int main()
{
    regex r("(aa.*|bb.*|cc.*)");
    cout<<regex_match("bb11",r)<<endl;  //return true
    cout<<regex_match("aa11",r)<<endl;  //return true
    cout<<regex_match("abc",r)<<endl;   //return false
    return 0;
}
```

I am wondering why "bb11" got different result?

Comment: That is really strange.  Using an online regex checker, both expressions yield true (as I would expect) for that case.

Comment: @bstar55: It's not "strange" at all. See my answer.

Comment: @lightness so it would seem nice catch!

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about that, thanks for the advice :) For you it's time to find a workarround your specific needs. Thanks for the question! (and @lightness for the answer)

Comment: @miguel-svq: FWIW, the obvious workaround is [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::regex` is not supported in GCC until 4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/560648).

In 4.8.2 you'll get all sorts of odd behaviour.

Comment: Jesus christ! Why is it even allowed! D:

Comment: @Rubens: Legacy, mostly.

Comment: Wow, good thing OP included the version of GCC being used...

Comment: @bstar55: Yeah I was about to tell him off for not bothering, then I noticed it up there tucked away ;p