# Troubles with non greedy C++ regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, regex-greedy

I want to parse the following Lua code:

```
[1]={['x']=198;['y']=74;['width']=99;['height']=199;};[2]={['x']=82;['y']=116;['width']=82;['height']=164;};
```

Notice that there are two keys in the table: `[1]` and `[2]`. I want to get only the value for the `[1]` key. How do I do that? I've tried the following:

```
cmatch res;
regex rx("\\[(.*)?\\]=\\{(.*)?\\};(.*)");
regex_search(lua_table.c_str(), res, rx);
```

But it's still greedy: it matches the entire text.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making your capturing groups optional by placing `?` outside of them. Instead, place them inside the groups `(.*?)` for a non-greedy match for the first two groupings and refer to capturing group `#2` for the match result.

```
\\[(.*?)\\]=\\{(.*?)\\};(.*)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU9sH6/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead and lookbehind to match all the chars which are present inside `{}` braces only if the closing brace is followed by `;` and any character,

```
(?<=\\{)(.*?)(?=\\};.)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eP7cH7/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @hwnd's, with a little more detailed info.

```
 # [1]={['x']=198;['y']=74;['width']=99;['height']=199;};[2]={['x']=82;['y']=116;['width']=82;['height']=164;};  
 #  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 108 ) 
 # [1]={['x']=198;['y']=74;['width']=99;['height']=199;};[2]={['x']=82;['y']=116;['width']=82;['height']=164;};  
 #  **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 1 ) 
 # 1  
 #  **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 5 , len 47 ) 
 # ['x']=198;['y']=74;['width']=99;['height']=199;  
 #  **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 54 , len 54 ) 
 # [2]={['x']=82;['y']=116;['width']=82;['height']=164;};  

 # "\\[(.*?)\\]=\\{(.*?)\\};(.*)"

 \[
 ( .*? )                       # (1)
 \]
 =
 \{
 ( .*? )                       # (2)
 \}
 ;
 ( .* )                        # (3)
```