# Hard to make clang+lldb work on centos7

Tags: clang, llvm, lldb, centos7, llvm-clang

I yum install clang, llvm-devel and lldb 3.4.2 on centos7. In order to add libc++ and libc++abi, I followed the guide in [How to Build libcxx and libcxxabi by clang on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840088/how-to-build-libcxx-and-libcxxabi-by-clang-on-centos-7). I only build libc++ without libc++abi and build libc++abi with libc++, and then workaround by copy `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cxxabi.h to /usr/local/include/`, otherwise cxxabi.h not be found.

With all these steps done, I am able to compile like `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi`. OK, I used this to compile my own program, when the program runs, I found the following log `exception_ptr not yet implemented`. And I can't find the root cause.

Also lldb doesn't work. I tried to lldb a.out, set breakpoint, and run. But not able to reach the breakpoint.

Could you please give me some hints on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I compiled llvm+lldb 3.7 from the source code instead of yum install, and when to compile test program, add -fno-limit-debug-info to CXX_FLAGS, and lldb works on centos7

Answer (score 0):

The Linux ports of lldb are in active development, but still have rough edges.  You might want to ping the lldb-dev list (lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org) as most of the people who are working on the Linux port hang out there.

Comment: Thanks, I sent my help to lldb-dev@lists.llvm.org