# How to install Clang and LLVM 3.9 on CentOS 7

Tags: clang, llvm

I have taken rpm packages from 
https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/alonid/llvm-3.9.0/epel-7-x86_64/00505197-clang-3.9.0/ for Clang 3.9.

I am installing the rpm packages by the command

```
rpm -ivh clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.src.rpm
```

But when I do

```
rpm -ivh clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the following error :

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    clang-3.9.0-libs(x86-64) = 3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libLLVM-3.9.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclang.so.3.9()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangAST.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangBasic.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangCodeGen.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangDriver.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangFormat.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangFrontend.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangFrontendTool.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangIndex.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangRewrite.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangRewriteFrontend.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangTooling.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
    libclangToolingCore.so()(64bit) is needed by clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64
```

Where should I install all these dependencies from?

Comment: Try the clang-libs rpm in that directory.

Comment: I am installing clang 3.9 on centos 7.3 . which rpm should i install from the following link : https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=clang-libs

Comment: Your post contains the link to https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/alonid/llvm-3.9.0/epel-7-x86_64/00505197-clang-3.9.0 , there are several rpms there. The error message you posted says "clang-3.9.0-libs(x86-64) = 3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid is needed by ..." Did you try installing both the clang and clang-libs rpm  from the link you posted ?

Answer (score 41):

By enabling the SCL repository you can install Clang 5.0.1 on CentOS 7 using the [`llvm-toolset-7`](https://pkgs.org/download/llvm-toolset-7-llvm) package.

```
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl
$ sudo yum install llvm-toolset-7
```

Enable `llvm-toolset-7`:

```
$ scl enable llvm-toolset-7 bash
```

You can now check you clang version with:

```
$ clang --version
```

See this [Red Hat blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/11/01/getting-started-llvm-toolset/) for more information.

For more information about SCL, see [this page](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/).

Comment: At this point in time Installing llvm-toolset-7 provides clang version 5.0.1

Comment: For anyone reading this post in 2020, the `scl enable` step should be written as:  `scl enable llvm-toolset-7 'bash'` or else you'll get an `Unable to open` error.
Source: https://developers.redhat.com/HW/ClangLLVM-RHEL-7

Answer (score 7):

There was a much easier way to achieve this:

Add the Alonid's repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` (assuming you have epel repo installed)

```
echo "[alonid-llvm-3.9.0]
name=Copr repo for llvm-3.9.0 owned by alonid
baseurl=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/alonid/llvm-
3.9.0/epel-7-$basearch/
type=rpm-md
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/alonid/llvm-
3.9.0/pubkey.gpg
repo_gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Then just `sudo yum install clang-3.9.0`

Comment: you need to escape the `$` in `$basearch`.. or else the shell will eat it

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of the RPM repository you mention.

Follow from the main Copr page of the repository:

https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/alonid/llvm-3.9.0/

If you have any question, you can contact me from there. Thanks!

Comment: Since 3.8.0, clang supports OpenMP. Where could I find libomp package for clang 3.8.0 on CentOS 7?

Comment: This is a link-only answer.

Comment: Hey @DanielLaügt did you happen to find out how to install?

Comment: I don't remember how I got libomp for clang 3.8.0... Since, I have installed clang 10 on CentOS 7. I'm doing this just by compiling the source code which is relatively simple: cmake3 -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='clang;clang-tools-extra;openmp' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/llvm-10.0.1 ../llvm; make –j8; sudo make install

Answer (score 1):

Just open [your link](https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/alonid/llvm-3.9.0/epel-7-x86_64/00505197-clang-3.9.0/) and look around, also go one level higher and find all necessary `.rpm`'s. The following sequence worked for me:

```
yum install compiler-rt-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
yum install clang-3.9.0-libs-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
yum install clang-3.9.0-3.9.0-3.1.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
yum install llvm-3.9.0-libs-3.9.0-7.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
yum install llvm-3.9.0-3.9.0-7.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
yum install llvm-3.9.0-devel-3.9.0-7.el7.centos.alonid.x86_64.rpm
```

By just doing `yum install` without any flags Clang and LLVM will be installed to `/opt/llvm-3.9.0`:

```
$ ls -l /opt/llvm-3.9.0 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  3 23:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  3 23:23 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  3 23:27 lib64
```

Also notice that there are other packages like `-devel`, `-static`, `-debuginfo`.

Useful tip: Without installing `-devel` packages you only get `bin` and `lib64` folders where only the executables like `bin/clang` and libraries like `lib64/libLLVM-3.9.0.so` are located. If you also want to develop something with LLVM/Clang you will need corresponding `-devel` packages. Then you will also get `include/` folder with headers.

By the way, thanks to the maintainers of this repo. Nice to have LLVM 3.9 out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

A complete installation process is provided by Red Hat, please refer to [Red Hat documents](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/07/07/yum-install-gcc7-clang/).