# "DSO missing from command line" when compiling with clang on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, clang, clang++, libc++

I am trying to compile a C++ program on an EC2 instance for use in aws lambda.  I am using a make file, and i enter

```
make -f Makefile
```

which seems to build the following expression:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -L/usr/lib/opencas -L/usr/lib -lTKBRep -lTKG2d -lTKG3d -lTKGeomBase -lTKMath -lTKMesh -lTKSTEP -lTKSTEP209 -lTKTopAlgo -lTKSTEPAttr -lTKSTEPBase -lTKSTL -lTKXSBase -lTKernel  -o step2stl lib.o main.o
```

Then I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3'
//usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [step2stl] Error 1
```

I've searched around but the only fix i've found was to add libc++ to the expression, but it seems like it is already there.

I've built this same program on Ubuntu without issues, but I had to install `libc++-dev` and `libc++abi-dev`

The only thing i can find for yum is `libcxx` (which i installed).  I'm stuck on what to do next...

**EDIT #1:**

I've installed `libcxxabi` and `libcxxabi-devel` packages from RPM here: https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-x86_64/libcxxabi-8.0.0-1.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html
But it still errors...

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libc++abi as well.

`_ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE` is the "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info".

Comment: is there a yum package for libc++abi?  The only thing I can find is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840088/how-to-build-libcxx-and-libcxxabi-by-clang-on-centos-7 ... Would that work?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know if there is a yum package for libc++abi