# Regexp runtime error in C++11

Tags: regex, c++11

This regex gives a runtime error

```
#include <regex>
int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
std::regex test("[^*]");
}
```

Error:

```
 ./test 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted
```

Presumabily because some of the things do not work in ecmascript c++11.
I've tried some variations (basic, extended, grep, egrep) but with no success.

How to do that regex in C++11 please?
(Boost is not an option).

Comment: We need [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)!

Comment: My personal experience with `<regex>` is that the different standard library has slight disagreement about the syntax. Which basically means practical non-portability.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the implementation of `<regex>` in C++11 is not complete until gcc 4.9.

[Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions)