# Conflicting regex results

Tags: c++, regex

I need to evaluate a regex on some data that I have. It is to get filenames from a string input in a specific order.

I have so far done this - http://regex101.com/r/rZ8tP0/1

PS: I am not well versed with regex, so kindly do not talk about this being non-optimal. Optimal solutions welcome.

The real issue is - I have a C++ program that does this. The program returns a 0 for the same string-regex combination, for which regex101 returns 1. What am I missing?

The C++ code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = "data-FileName-author-data-";
    string r = "(.+-){1}FileName-(.+-){2}";
    cout<<regex_match(s, regex(r))<<"\n"; //returns 0
}
```

Comment: Which compiler? Version?

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 and I compile using the std=c++0x flag

Comment: Reopened - that was very bad judgement.

Comment: @MSalters: Similar problem has been asked more than once, from incorrect result to error. I admit the choice of the question is poor, but this question should be closed as dup nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated.

Comment: Also your online regex tester is configured to use PCRE style regex whereas C++11, by default, uses ECMAScript (iirc). So probably best to set your online tester to Javascript mode (JS).

Comment: @nhahtdh: If you think it should be closed as duplicate, find one that addresses inconsistent results.

Comment: @MSalters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc4-7-buggy-about-regular-expressions This one looks somewhat OK as dup.

Comment: I fully agree - confirmed by the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which compiler you use? If gcc - only gcc 4.9+ supports correct work for regexes.
[Live example on Coliru, that shows 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6608dbef26c9d66)

Comment: Thanks. I will check that up.