# regex_error in C++ with really simple expression

Tags: c++, regex

I have a set of strings like this violet+2, orange-3 and things like that. It is a way to name colours. I want to get the color, operation and number with regex using this piece of code:

```
int parseColor(string color){
smatch sm;
int ret = -1;
    if (regex_match(color,sm,regex("(.*)([+-])(.*)")))
        ret = s_colors[sm[1].str()]+s_colors[sm[2].str()]*atoi(sm[3].str().c_str());

return ret;
}
```

where s_colors is a map that matches each colour to a integer value and the +,- sign to +1 and -1.

I have tried also scaping the +- signs with \\+ and \\- but it doesn't work either. Every time I run I get regex_error. Trying this in ruby seems to work so... I am not sure what is the error with the regex.

Comment: What is your compiler? Where is your testcase?

Comment: I am using now gcc 4.8.2 and with every string with the format I posted before it crashes. For example, violet+2 doesn't work (just picking one).

Comment: Manuel beat me to it, but your compiler _does not support regexes_. Therefore this is a near-enough duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12530406/560648.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gcc 4.8.2 does not support regex. You need 4.9

Comment: I thouhgt that using the c++11 flag would be enough. Thanks a lot then, I will try something else.