# C++11 std::regex_replace behavior using clang 3.5.0 and libstdc++ 4.8.2

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

I've been trying to understand the behavior of the following simple regex command when using std::regex_replace. I'm trying to extract the filename on a linux system from a full path.

```
std::string fullPath = "/folder/subfolder/fname.xyz";
std::string fname = std::regex_replace( fullPath, std::regex( std::string(".*/")), std::string(""));
```

Where fname becomes an empty string. Is this expected behavior of std::regex_replace? I would have expected fname to be "fname.xyz" after the calls.

#### Update

I compile the program on Ubuntu 14.04 with compiler flags:

```
CXX = clang++ WFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unknown-pragmas CXXFLAGS = $(WFLAGS) -Werror -g -std=c++11 -pthread
```

The internal abi version of libstdc++ is 3.4.19. Extracted using:

```
readelf -sV /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | sed -n 's/.*@@GLIBCXX_//p' | sort -u -V | tail -1
```

The libstdc++ version of Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) is 4.8.2.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?  [I'm getting your expected result](http://ideone.com/iRneCE), but some compilers have been slow at getting regex conformance.

Comment: clang++ (clang 3.5.0) on a x86_64 machine.

Comment: What version of libstdc++ or libc++ are you using?

Comment: Might be related to https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21363

Comment: Tested with more recent clang and had an expected result: http://rextester.com/live/AAX59324

Comment: `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: @tisch: Sadly, that's not helpful. Instead, could you tell me the compiler flags you are using and what release of the linux distribution you are using is? (or bsd or whatever)

Comment: Compiler flags:
`CXX = clang++
WFLAGS=-Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-unknown-pragmas
CXXFLAGS = $(WFLAGS) -Werror -g -std=c++11 -pthread`
on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I can confirm the libstdc++ version is 3.4.19 using: `readelf -sV /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | sed -n 's/.*@@GLIBCXX_//p' | sort -u -V | tail -1`

Comment: @tisch: So that's actually an internal abi version. You're using [libstdc++-4.8.2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libstdc++-4.8-dev).

Comment: @BillLynch thanks for the clarification on the version!

Comment: @nhahtdh: please clarify your decision to close this question. I don't see this as a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-7-and-gcc-4-8-buggy-about-regular-expressions).

Comment: @tisch: The question is not a duplicate, but the underlying issue is generally the same. There is currently no mechanism on SO to indicate that "all the problems in these question can be traced to this issue on upstream". I'm tired of seeing all these `<regex>`  library questions all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling with a libstdc++ before 4.9.0. This version of the c++ standard library does not properly implement `<regex>`.

The only real solution is to upgrade the version of `libstdc++` that you are compiling against.

[**Would you like to know more?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-7-and-gcc-4-8-buggy-about-regular-expressions)