# What is the exact way of using regex_iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, regex

I have been looking for a good way to calculate the number of sub-strings of a particular type in a string, say, I want to count the occurrences of 'sms' in the string 'smstyuismsms'. I found an answer in a forum where somebody suggested making use of regex_iterator. But, when I tried it as follows:

```
string in = "smstyuismssms";
cout << distance(regex_iterator(in.begin(), in.end(), regex("sms")),regex_iterator()) << "\n";
```

It throws an error saying

> error: missing template arguments before '(' token

So, if not this, then what is the correct way of using regex template? Please provide some examples as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator), it seems std::regex_iterator is the template from which four instantiations exist:

```
cregex_iterator    regex_iterator<const char*>
wcregex_iterator   regex_iterator<const wchar_t*>
sregex_iterator    regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>
wsregex_iterator   regex_iterator<std::wstring::const_iterator>
```

you should use these instead. I mean, you can always pass the template argument yourself but that's needlessly verbose.

From the cppreference example:

```
auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
```

This is much like `std::string`/`std::wstring` which are both instantiations of the `std::basic_string` template. Basically your code is the equivalent of using basic_string and not passing the template argument instead of using string/wstring directly.

Comment: Hi! I first tried it by using the same example only. But sregex_iterator threw an error "undefined reference to regex". When I searched for the issue, I found that the compiler that I am using(gcc4.8.1) probably doesn't support this instantiation. So, then, I switched to regex_iterator.

Comment: @timidgeek [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-7-and-gcc-4-8-buggy-about-regular-expressions), I'm afraid your compiler might be too old.

Comment: Fine. I'll update my compiler and ask if any problem persists. Thank you.