# Why can't std::regex_search find the right overload?

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio

I have a simple regex problem in Visual Studio 2017. As far as I can tell this should match the [#2 overload at cppreference.com for `std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) but the compiler is returning a ton of errors. This is the entire program.

```
#include <regex>

int main()
{
   std::basic_regex<char> rx("This");
   std::match_results<char> mat;
   std::regex_search("This is a test.", mat, rx, std::regex_constants::match_continuous);
   return 0;
}
```

And here's the entire inscrutable error list.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RegexError, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>RegexError.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): error C2039: 'difference_type': is not a member of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): note: see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(6): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): error C3646: 'difference_type': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1185): error C2039: 'value_type': is not a member of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): note: see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(646): error C2039: 'value_type': is not a member of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): note: see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1422): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::sub_match<_BidIt>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(646): error C3646: 'value_type': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(646): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(647): error C2039: 'difference_type': is not a member of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(1182): note: see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_BidIt>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(647): error C3646: 'difference_type': unknown override specifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(647): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2672: 'std::regex_search': no matching overloaded function found
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2780: 'bool std::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2948): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2784: 'bool std::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &&,std::match_results<basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc>::const_iterator,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &&' from 'const char [16]'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2936): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2784: 'bool std::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &,std::match_results<basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc>::const_iterator,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &' from 'const char [16]'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2919): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2784: 'bool std::regex_search(const _Elem *,std::match_results<const _Elem*,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::match_results<const _Elem*,_Alloc> &' from 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2904): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2780: 'bool std::regex_search(const _Elem *,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2890): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2782: 'bool std::regex_search(_BidIt,_BidIt,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': template parameter '_BidIt' is ambiguous
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2877): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): note: could be 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): note: or       'const char *'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2784: 'bool std::regex_search(_BidIt,_BidIt,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for '_BidIt' from 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2877): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2782: 'bool std::regex_search(_BidIt,_BidIt,std::match_results<_BidIt,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': template parameter '_BidIt' is ambiguous
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2864): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): note: could be 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): note: or       'const char *'
1>f:\sandbox\regexerror\regexerror\regexerror.cpp(7): error C2784: 'bool std::regex_search(_BidIt,_BidIt,std::match_results<_BidIt,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)': could not deduce template argument for '_BidIt' from 'std::match_results<char,std::allocator<std::sub_match<_BidIt>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _BidIt=char
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\regex(2864): note: see declaration of 'std::regex_search'
1>Done building project "RegexError.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the overload from `<regex>` that I think it should be matching.

```
template<class _Elem,
    class _Alloc,
    class _RxTraits> inline
    bool regex_search(_In_z_ const _Elem *_Str,
        match_results<const _Elem *, _Alloc>& _Matches,
        const basic_regex<_Elem, _RxTraits>& _Re,
        regex_constants::match_flag_type _Flgs =
            regex_constants::match_default)
    {   // search for regular expression match in target text
    const _Elem *_Last = _Str + char_traits<_Elem>::length(_Str);
    return (_Regex_search1(_Str, _Last, &_Matches, _Re, _Flgs, _Str));
    }
```

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but *I think* `std::match_results<char> mat;` should be `std::cmatch mat;` (looking at [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results))

Comment: You are passing a `const char*` rather than a `std::string`. Also `std::match_results` needs an iterator not a `char` template parameter (use `std::smatch`.

Comment: Oh that would work to. Either use `std::cmatch` and pass a `const char*` or use an `std::smatch` and pass a `std::string`.

Comment: @Galik there are many overloads, one takes `std::string` and one takes `const char*`, my question is why it appears to be trying to select the wrong one. And looking at the actual template parameter for `match_results` doesn't support your conclusion either.

Comment: `std::match_results` needs an iterator, either a `std::string::iterator` (smatch) or a `char*` (cmatch).

Comment: @Borgleader you should have left that as an answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom I could have, but I wasn't sure it was correct. I don't use `<regex>` at all. I just happen to have answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30460242/583833).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second overload expects a

```
std::match_results<const CharT*,Alloc>
```

for the second parameter.  This does not not match `mat` which has the type

```
std::match_results<char>
```

Changing it to

```
std::match_results<const char*>
```

Should work

Additionally, you can just use a `std::cmatch` instead as it is defined as a `std::match_results<const char*>`

Comment: @MarkRansom No problem.

Comment: Or the "shorthand" `std::cmatch`

Comment: @Borgleader in my case since I'm using Microsoft I want something that's templated on `TCHAR`, so this is perfect.

Comment: Oh that makes sense then.