# How to match one of multiple alternative patterns with C++11 regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

With Perl, the following results in a match:

```
echo xyz | perl -ne 'print if (/.*(yes|no|xy).*/);'
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing with a C++ regex. The [ECMAScript syntax documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/) says

> A regular expression can contain multiple alternative patterns simply
>   by separating them with the separator operator (|): The regular
>   expression will match if any of the alternatives match, and as soon as
>   one does.

However, the following example seems to suggest that std::regex_match only matches the first two alternatives, ignoring the third:

```
std::string pattern1 = ".*(yes|no|xy).*";
std::string pattern2 = ".*(yes|xy|no).*";
std::regex re1(pattern1);
std::regex re2(pattern2);
for (std::string str : {"yesplease", "bayes", "nobody", "anode", "xyz", "abc"} ) {
   if (std::regex_match(str,re1)) {
       std::cout << str << "\t\tmatches " << pattern1 << "\n";
   }
   else if (std::regex_match(str,re2)) {
       std::cout << str << "\t\tmatches " << pattern2 << "\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
yesplease   matches .*(yes|no|xy).*
bayes       matches .*(yes|no|xy).*
nobody      matches .*(yes|no|xy).*
anode       matches .*(yes|no|xy).*
xyz         matches .*(yes|xy|no).*
```

How can I obtain the same behaviour as with my Perl regex example, i.e. having 'xyz' match pattern1?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Because both gcc and clang match `xyz` to `pattern1`.

Comment: I'm using gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: Why did you remove the delimiters?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which delimiters?

Comment: @j_h: The regex delimiters. But, never mind, turns out their inclusion is not supported. :sadface:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `regex` is not fully implemented in gcc version 4.8.2 but rather in later versions of gcc (i.e., version > 4.9.0).

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53631

In gcc version 4.9.0 works ok [LIVE DEMO](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/S7hcBkSRjkPVzPwI)

So I guess you'll have to upgrade to newer version of gcc.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just before you posted the answer I tried upgrading to 4.9.2, and now it seems to work.

Comment: It seems this issue was discussed here before, although that post didn't come up in any of my searches
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/3893211