# can't run the program compiled using minGW in windows using regex c++11 std

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, mingw

This program compiles fine without any error but when i run the program it exits unexpectedly saying it ran into some problem .

Analyzing using gdb  the program runs into segmentation fault. I dont know much about gdb so can't examine thoroughly if somebody can reproduce the problem and explain the error that will be helpful.

Also what can i do to rectify the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   bool found;
   cmatch m;
try
{
    found = regex_search("<html>blah blah blah </html>",m,regex("<.*>.* </\\1"));
    cout<< found<<endl<<m.str();
}
catch(exception & e)
{

    cout<<e.what();
}

return 0;


}
```

Comment: What gcc version are you using? `<regex>` is broken on versions < 4.9. Read https://stackoverflow.com/q/12530406/241631

Comment: Which is your exact GCC version? It's well known that `std::regex` didn't work before version 4.9

Comment: yeah my gcc is 4.8.1 and its the latest version available with minGW ,is there any way i can change that?

Comment: @rahultyagi Try `MinGW-W64`. It has newer version of gcc.

Comment: @Praetorian I think the questions are actually different - the OP's code actually has a bug in the regex definition which is causing his program to crash.

Comment: @RichardHodges Maybe so, but as posted, if the OP is using gcc4.8, no amount of correcting the regex pattern will make his program run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your back reference needs to refer to a group.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<regex>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool found;
    cmatch m;
    try
    {
        found = regex_search("<html>blah blah blah </html>",m,regex("<(.*)>(.*)</\\1>"));
        cout << "***whole match***\n";
        cout << "found=" << found << endl;
        cout << m.str() << endl;

        cout << "\n*** parts ***" << endl;
        for (const auto& c : m) {
            cout << c << endl;
        }

    }
    catch(exception & e)
    {

        cout<<e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;


}
```

expected output:

```
***whole match***
found=1
<html>blah blah blah </html>

*** parts ***
<html>blah blah blah </html>
html
blah blah blah
```

Comment: i get what you  are saying but maybe you got the question wrong , the program exits unexpectedly

Comment: regex_search has a number of template overloads, depending on how much information you want. The problem you had was that the stdlib wanted to tell you that the regex was invalid (should have thrown an exception). Instead, it crashed. On clang with libc++ your program threw the exception and it was reported on stdout.

Comment: your program is same as that of mine except that you traversed through m

Comment: @rahultyagi not quite - compare the strings of the regex definitions - mine has round brackets to create the first group inside the opening html tag, which is then referred back to by the back-reference in the closing tag.

Comment: ah yes seems like i posted the question in hurry even if i do that it won't run on my machine as the comments to the original question stated but thanks for the answer i appreciate your effort

Comment: @rahultyagi ah ok - in that case you'll get better results using boost::regex which is almost identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81990/discussion-between-rahul-tyagi-and-richard-hodges).