# C++ (C++11) regular expressions differences on OS X and Linux

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to get my code to work on both OS X and Linux the same.
The code below is compiled with `clang++ --std=c++11 regextest.cpp`

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "/api/asd/";
    std::string pattern = "/api/(.*)/";
    std::cout << "Starting matching" << std::endl;
    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_match(str, matches, std::regex(pattern, std::regex::egrep)))
    {
        std::cout << "Found match!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "All matches: ";
        for (auto& it : matches)
            std::cout << it << ", ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On OS X, the result of running this code is:

```
Starting matching
Found match!
All matches: /api/asd/, asd,
```

On Linux, on the other hand (Gentoo, libstdc++ 3.3)

```
Starting matching
Found match!
All matches: /api/asd/, /asd/, //
```

How does it match `/api/` on Linux? Why?

Additionally, trying to use a pattern like `/api/([^/])` fails completely in Linux and matches nothing but works well in OS X.

I've tried many combinations of match types, (basic, extended, grep, egrep, awk) with escaped and unescaped `(` and `)` (depending on the match type) and nothing produces the expected results on Linux.

Comment: Looks like theres something wrong with your compiler on Linux. Try using GCC, and make sure its updated.

Comment: The libstdc++ version that shipped with g++-4.9 was the first to support `<regex>`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/241631. My guess is you're using an older version.

Comment: Have you tried using `std::regex::ECMAScript` instead of `std::regex::egrep`? I'm not sure what are the peculiarieties of egrep's regular expressions, but ECMAScript's should work fine.

Comment: Which gcc version are you using?

Comment: libstdc++ 3.3 doesn't look correct.

Comment: I found regex in the std (in linux) to behave differently than boost regex, so I think std regex has some bugs, in the past at least.

Comment: @n.m. gcc --version: `gcc (Gentoo 4.8.4 p1.4, pie-0.6.1) 4.8.4`

Comment: I don't understand, though, why matching works at all, but only seemingly incorrectly if there is absolutely no regex support.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the comments, this issue was solved by upgrading gcc to 4.9. (~amd64 flag currently required to do this on Gentoo).