# from which version std::regex is available in libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, ubuntu, software-packaging

I have written a tool in C++ which uses [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) features. It uses `std::regex` to provide regex functionality.

It requires GCC (>=4.9.0) to compile the code.

This is the error message on a Ubuntu system where `libstdc++6` is not installed.

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
```

I am packaging this software for Ubuntu, but can not figure out which version of `libstdc++6` should I put as a dependency of my program.

And what will be the dependency of this program for a general case regarding all Unix like OS that I should notify the user beforehand?

Comment: Are you asking which version of GCC first supported `std::regex` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408#12665408), or which version of GCC you have linked to? And what does the last sentence mean?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I just want to notify the user about it's dependency i.e what they need to run it properly. Making them to install the whole gcc >=4.9 package seems not very feasible.

Comment: So then they need the libstdc++6-4.9.x package, for some x. I don't understand what you're asking. You compiled with GCC 4.9, you linked with GCC 4.9, so your program needs the libstdc++ from (at least) GCC 4.9 ... isn't the answer just 4.9? If not, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am packaging this software for Ubuntu, but can not figure out which version of libstdc++6 should I put as a dependency of my program.

The minimum dependency is the version that you linked your program with.

So if you linked with `gcc-4.9.1` then they need at least `libstdc++6-4.9.1`

> And what will be the dependency of this program for a general case regarding all Unix like OS that I should notify the user beforehand?

It needs a compiler that supports `std::regex` from C++11 ... but you already said that in the question.