# How to work with regular expressions in c++ with gcc 4.8 and without C++11 flag?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc, gcc4.9

I recently found out that regex support in gcc 4.8 is incomplete, and it was truly implemented in gcc 4.9 (see [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions)).

So, wanting to work with regex in my c++ program, I updated my gcc to 4.9 following this instructions (https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Now when I try to compile my program it says that in order to `#include <regex>` I have to specify the compiler flag `-std=c++11`, which I did, and now I'm faced with new compilation problems that I didn' had before (`‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member`).

Given that, I think for now it is best to stick to gcc 4.8 and not specify the gnu++11 flag in compilation. Back to square 1.

So, can I work with regular expressions in c++ if I do not want to switch to gcc 4.9 nor flag the compiler with c++11? Is there another way?

Thanks!

PS: actually it's the c++11 flag that causes the compilation issues, not the version of gcc, right?

Comment: The error you're getting makes it seem like what you have is not valid C++03 code. You were only allowed to initialize static integral members in their declaration back then. I don't know why anything different would compile, but it would likely be specific to GCC.

Comment: @chris Could be... I have a lot of legacy code to work with. Since I'm not specifying a standard, do you know if gcc defaults to C++03?

Comment: It defaults to C++98 with GCC extensions. As of GCC 6.0, it will default to C++14 with GCC extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library and use that instead of the C++11 standard regular expressions.  PCRE is really designed as a C library/interface, rather than C++, but writing a couple of trivial wrapper classes or just using it as a C library is quite easy.

Comment: Or even PCRE2 if you need more regex power :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error most likely means you were relying on a [non-standard GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html) to initialize a non-integer type like this:

```
struct X {
  static const double d = 3.14;
};
```

That was not valid in C++98, but was supported by GCC.

The C++11 standard added support for initializing non-integer types like that, but you need to use `constexpr` e.g.

```
struct X {
  static constexpr double d = 3.14;
};
```

When you compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` the old GCC-specific extension is no longer supported. and you have to use the standard C++11 way, using `constexpr`.

So you could easily resolve the error by changing it to `constexpr`, or to make it compatible with GCC's C++98 extension and also C++11:

```
struct X {
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
  static constexpr double d = 3.14;
#else
  // this is non-standard but allowed by GCC in C++98 mode
  static const double d = 3.14;
#endif
};
```

That will allow you to compile with `-std=c++11`, and so you can use GCC 4.9's working `std::regex`.