# function regex of C++ different result in CentOS and OSX

Tags: c++, regex, linux, macos

I try to write a program to test regular expression in C++, so I read and following the standard example, my code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char var1[10] = "12345";
string var2 = "12345";

int main()
{
    if (regex_match( var1, regex( "\\d+" ) ) ){
        printf("var1 match\n");
    }else{
        printf("var1 not match\n");
    }
    if (regex_match( var2, regex( "\\d+" ) ) ){
        printf("var2 match\n");
    }else{
        printf("var2 not match\n");
    }
}
```

Then I run command like following for compile and run:

```
g++ retest.cpp -o retest -std=c++0x
./retest
```

But it show me following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
Aborted
```

I modified the code and finally found that error cause regular string in regex(). But when I write same code in my OSX, it can run and show me the correct result!
I am so confused that why I use the standard C++ library, but different result in CentOS and OSX?
How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: See [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/3832970) *How can I solve this problem?* > Upgrade to the latest GCC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS has quite old GCC package. You can check it details in http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos

On my CentOS 7 machine says,

```
# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

and, `<regex>` was implemented in gcc 4.9.0. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/3627572

Comment: My CentOS7 is "gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC) ", so it seems I have to upgrade my gcc and g++, but there is nothing happend after I type "yum upgrade gcc gcc-c++"

Comment: And I confused why gcc shows 'std::regex_error' but regex not support in this version