# regex_match fails to find square brackets

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to do regex_match on a string which have square brackets(`[...]`) inside it.

Things I have tried so far:

- Normal matching
- Backslashing the square brackets with 1 slash
- Backslashing the square brackets with 2 slashes

Code to repro:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  std::string str1 = "a/b/c[2]/d";
  std::string str2 = "(.*)a/b/c[2]/d(.*)";
  std::regex e(str2);

  std::cout << "str1 = " << str1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "str2 = " << str2 << std::endl;
  if (regex_match(str1, e)) {
    std::cout << "matched" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This is the error message I get every time I compile it.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what():  regex_error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was told by stack overflow members that gcc 4.8 or earlier version of it are known to be buggy. So, I needed to update it to latest version.

I have created an [Ideone fiddle](https://ideone.com/fJEKAF) where compiler should not be issue. **Even there, I do not see regex_match happening.**

Comment: What is the GCC version?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thread model: posix gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: So, all the answers are not helpful. Just upgrade your gcc compiler to some recent version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It might be. But then should'nt it work on ideone.com. I tested code there and it did not match at all. Btw, I did not get any regex_error there.


At : https://ideone.com/fJEKAF

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/LfZ09p), you made some mistakes in the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, where are you using square brackets in your regex/strings to be compare? What you wrote it just a plain and simple regex which btw works with 4.8 as well.

Comment: If you need to actually match square brackets, you do need to escape them. Please see my answer below, and if there are any questions, please drop a comment there.

Comment: @To SO users: This is not a dupe of [*Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions), please consider reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you have is the outdated gcc compiler: you need to upgrade to some recent version. 4.8.x just does not support regex as it should.

Now, the code you should be using is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    std::string str1 = "a/b/c[2]/d";
    std::string str2 = R"(a/b/c\[2]/d)";
    std::regex e(str2);

    std::cout << "str1 = " << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str2 = " << str2 << std::endl;
    if (regex_search(str1, e)) {
        std::cout << "matched" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/LfZ09p)

Use

- `regex_search` instead of `regex_match` to search for *partial matches* (`regex_match` requires a full string match)
- The `[2]` in the regex pattern matches a literal `2` (`[...]` is a character class matching 1 character from the range/list specified in the character class). To match the literal square brackets, you need to escape the `[` and you do not have to escape `]`: `R"(a/b/c\[2]/d)"`.

Comment: where are you using square brackets in your regex/strings to be compare? What you wrote it just a plain and simple regex which btw works with 4.8 as well

Comment: Completely make sense after you introduced slashes in your code. Thanks!

Comment: You may read more on what characters should be escaped for the regex engine to treat them literally [here](http://regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer proved useful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Well they should definitely be escaped by using a backslash. Unfortunately since backslash is itself special in a literal string you need two backslashes. So the regex should look like `"(.*)a/b/c\\[2\\]/d(.*)"`.

Comment: I am afraid to tell it do not work.

Comment: The forward slashes might also need escaping... ``"\\/"``

Comment: @BitTickler. Nope that is not true. Write this code without square brackets and it would match. Even with forward slashes.

Comment: On https://regex101.com/, this one seems to do the job: ``(.*)a\/b\/c\[2\]\/d(.*)`` Some more backslashing added to accomodate the c-string literal stuff and you might be there.

Comment: @BitTickler, For c++? It might work for perl/python.

Comment: is that not an ISO standard or something? Lol - I never use regex and assumed they all work the same everywhere.

Comment: The error I get when testing is indeed `std::regex_constants::error_escape`, but I'm not sure *what* needs to be escaped.

Comment: Oh and for those who wonders, it's not the `std::regex_match` call that throws, but the `std::regex` object construction.

Answer (score 0):

Raw string literals often simplify cases where one would otherwise have to have complex escape sequences:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    std::string str1 = "a/b/c[2]/d";
    std::string str2 = R"regex((.*)a/b/c[2]/d(.*))regex";
    std::regex e(str2);

    std::cout << "str1 = " << str1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str2 = " << str2 << std::endl;
    if (regex_match(str1, e)) {
        std::cout << "matched" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
str1 = a/b/c[2]/d
str2 = (.*)a/b/c[2]/d(.*)
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this. Initially, I thought it was a good idea to try your code. Unfortunately, it did not work. Still giving me same 'std::regex_error'.

Comment: There is nothing to escape in OP pattern. The failure is most likely due to the old GCC version.

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: @HemantBhargava eek. gcc 4.8 is known to be buggy. upgrade to 5.3 asap!