# regex_search C++ not matching substrings

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

regex_search is not matching "ter" in "Computer Computer" when I'm using following code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str("Computer Computer");
    cout << regex_search(str, regex("ter"));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives me 0, whereas there obviously is "ter" in the subject. So what is going on here. I know PHP's regex matches the substring just fine, but whats wrong here?

I'm using C++11 GCC, is that a problem since I read somewhere it has a poor support for regex.

Comment: What header file are you using?

Comment: I used your exact code in my CodeBlocks and it's giving me 0, which means there is a compiler problem here.

Comment: are you sure your compiler is set to use gcc-11..the link i gave was for c++ 14.. i am also getting 0

Comment: Yup, exclusively set it the compiler options, I see ideon.com is using C++14. Will try out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reruns 1 type bool, it means pattern match found in the word .Run this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    cout << regex_search(string("Computer Computer"), regex("ter"));//1
    cout << regex_search(string("Computer Computer"), regex("tesdsr"));//0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close but no cigar, still getting 00. :(

Comment: @DivyaMamgai this program is correct, but if you have the gcc compiler with version 4.8 or earlier, then [its Standard Library does not provide a working `<regex>` implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12530406/819272). Upgrade to gcc 4.9 or later.

Comment: Yes, just installed Cygwin with GCC 5.3 and everything is working great.