# 8 seconds for regex_match("", regex(".{40000}"));?

Tags: c++, regex, performance

**Update 2:** Actually it's the `regex(".{40000}");`. That alone already takes that much time. Why?

---

`regex_match("", regex(".{40000}"));` takes almost 8 seconds on my PC. Why? Am I doing something wrong? I'm using gcc 4.9.3 from MinGW on Windows 10 on an i7-6700.

Here's a full test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t t = clock();
    regex_match("", regex(".{40000}"));
    cout << double(clock() - t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}
```

How I compile and run it:

```
C:\Users\ ... \coding>g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp

C:\Users\ ... \coding>a.exe
7.643
```

---

**Update:** Looks like the time is quadratic in the given number. Doubling it roughly quadruples the time:

```
  10000   0.520 seconds (factor 1.000)
  20000   1.922 seconds (factor 3.696)
  40000   7.810 seconds (factor 4.063)
  80000  31.457 seconds (factor 4.028)
 160000 128.904 seconds (factor 4.098)
 320000 536.358 seconds (factor 4.161)
```

The code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double prev = 0;
    for (int i=10000; ; i*=2) {
        clock_t t0 = clock();
        regex_match("", regex(".{" + to_string(i) + "}"));
        double t = double(clock() - t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("%7d %7.3f seconds (factor %.3f)\n", i, t, prev ? t / prev : 1);
        prev = t;
    }
}
```

Still no idea **why**. It's a very simple regex and the empty string (though it's the same with short non-empty strings). It should fail **instantly**. Is the regex engine just weird and bad?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does that really matter? I'm trying to check words like "internationalization" against abbreviations like "i12iz4n" by translating the latter to regexes like "i.{12}iz.{4}n".

Comment: Perhaps you need to get a newer version of g++. I just ran your program with gcc 6.2.0 and it finished in 118ms.

Comment: Do not allow processing empty strings, check them before passing to the `regex_match` method. BTW, on GCC 5.1, [it takes much less time](http://ideone.com/MZT017).

Comment: @Waxrat Looks like I already have the newest version that MinGW offers. Also, 118ms is still a lot. I'd expect it to be done instantly, as it has pretty much nothing to do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not just empty strings, I just made the example minimal. Also, your 22ms is still a lot for pretty much not having to do anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I now tried my updated tester there. Looks like it takes linear time and it it causes a "regex_error" for 160000: http://ideone.com/XqnCSQ

Comment: On my machine your code runs instantly as expected. `$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0`

Comment: The parsing & construction of the regex `regex(".{40000}")` takes most of the time (74ms), and `regex_match` takes 0.6ms.

Comment: Just tested the second code on my pc (i7-4790K). The factor is constantly about 2. Using g++ 6.2.1 or clang++ 3.9 doesn't make much difference. Without optimization the example with i=80000 runs in about 0.1sec, with optimization in about 0.02sec

Comment: Using g++ 4.8 actually makes a huge difference - the i=80000 example runs in 0.000sec. The first one that needs 0.001sec is i=640000. Can't explain why

Comment: And g++ 4.6 is even quicker and the first one that needs 0.001sec is i=1280000 - really strange

Comment: @msrd0 That difference between your 4.6 and your 4.8 could maybe be just random variation. Do you happen to have 4.9 as well? I guess maybe they extended the regex capabilities in 4.9 but did it in a naive way, and then until 6.2.1 they made it faster...

Comment: @StefanPochmann that are the default values for both 4.6 and 4.8 after a lot of runs but the difference isn't really big. i can install 4.9 and test it but it will take some time to compile

Comment: @msrd0 Actually apparently [until 4.9, regex isn't supported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/1672429) but the compiler doesn't say so.

Comment: @msrd0 Thanks, but don't bother installing 4.9 unless you really want to yourself :-)

Comment: @StefanPochmann with gcc 4.9.3 I get the same results as you posted so probably you should update your compiler

Answer (score 2):

Because it want be fast...

It very possible that transform this regex to another representation (state machine or something else) that is easier and faster to run. C# allow even generating runtime code that represents regex.

In your case you probably hit some bug in that transformation that have `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: why should that be a bug?

Comment: @msrd0 This is more performance bug that functionality one. It give you correct answer but in infective manner.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring the construction and matching separately:

```
clock_t t1 = clock();
regex r(".{40000}");
clock_t t2 = clock();
regex_match("", r);
clock_t t3 = clock();

cout << double(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << '\n'
     << double(t3 - t2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

I see:

```
0.077336
0.000613
```

Comment: Using which compiler? In this case it's very important, as comments on the question indicate that different compilers give very different results.

Comment: Using gcc 6.2.0