# Segmentation fault c++ regex

Tags: regex, c++11, segmentation-fault

I am getting a "Segmentation fault" when I try to use some regular expressions.  In this example, the first regular expression worked fine, but the second produced a segmentation fault:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void out(const string& s, const string& d,bool b) { cout << s << ", " << d << (b ? "=found" : "=not found") << endl; }

int
main()
{
    const auto exp1 = string{"<.*>.*</.*>"};
    const auto reg1 = regex{exp1};
    const auto data1 = string{"<tag>value</tag>"};
    const auto found1 = regex_match(data1, reg1);
    out(exp1, data1, found1);

    const auto exp2 = string{"<(.*)>.*</\\1>"};

    cout << "About to create the regex!" << endl;
    const auto reg2 = regex{exp2};
    cout << "done." << endl;

    const auto data2 = string{"<tag>value</tag>"};
    const auto found2 = regex_match(data2, reg2);
    out(exp2, data2, found2);

    cout << "All done!" << endl;
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
g++ -O0 -g -Wall -Wpedantic -std=c++11    try3.cpp   -o try3
```

And when I run it I get this:

```
$ ./try3
<.*>.*</.*>, <tag>value</tag>=found
About to create the regex!
Segmentation fault
```

I am running on CentOS release 5.11 with libstdc++-4.1.2-55.el5

Comment: That is a problem with the compiled regex library, not the regex itself. You can tell if it's this if you put a try/catch around that line, but it is never caught.

Comment: @sln: true, I tried earlier with a try statement and it does not catch anything.  Do you (or others) have a work-around?

Comment: Not for sure, but google the problem, it's probably either the lib version or what flags were set when compiled. Somebody should pass by that knows for sure.

Comment: Do you also have the same issue with `<[^>]*>[^<]*</[^>]*>` or `"<([^<]+)>[\\s\\S]*?</\\1>"`? If yes, the problem is with the outdated regex library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because GCC 4.1 was starting to implement regex but it was not ready for use until later.

See [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions/12665408?s=3|1.0888#12665408)