# Where can the C++11/14/17 support for specific libstdc++ releases be found?

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++

I recently lost several hours of work because of the fact that the libstdc++ version bundled with GCC 4.8 [contained an incomplete C++11 `<regex>` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/1398841). I'd like to be able to know about missing stdlib features before running into problems like this.

I assumed that because [GCC 4.8 supported nearly all of the C++11 *language* features](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html) it also implemented all of the C++11 standard library features.

Where can I check which C++11/14/17 standard library features are available in each libstdc++ release that correspond to GCC releases? [The libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) appears to only the feature list from the latest release of libstdc++.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z

Comment: Is there a good reason you cannot upgrade to a newer version of gcc?

Comment: @AlexZywicki A requirement of the software is that it builds on the native CentOS 7 compiler, in this case GCC 4.8.5. But more broadly, even if I moved to a new compiler, I'd still like to know the answer as it applies to, say, C++20 or future language versions.

Comment: @Galik That link (while helpful) doesn't address libstdc++. For example, searching for "regex" doesn't lend any hits, so it wouldn't have helped find this particular problem.

Comment: @phoenix is the requirement that it _builds_ with the native CentOS 7 compiler, or just that it only depends on the native CentOS 7 version of `libstdc++.so`? You might be able to build using `devtoolset-7-gcc-c++` (installable from the CentOS Software Collections). That provides a much newer GCC that produces binaries that don't have any dynamic dependency on the newer libstdc++, so will run on any CentOS 7 system.