# How can libstdc++ from devtoolset-7 be linked against when building on CentOS 7?

Tags: c++11, g++, centos7, libstdc++, devtoolset

I would like to use [`devtoolset-7`](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/) to build a C++11 application on CentOS 7. I am trying to use the [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library, but the version of `libstdc++` included natively with CentOS 7, 4.8.4, [does not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/1398841).

I have followed the following instructions to install and enable SCL/`devtoolset-7`:

```
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-7
$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```

At this point, if I invoke `g++`, it is the proper version (7.2.1), but when I build applications and run `ldd` on them, they are still dynamically linked to the old `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` on the system. What is the simplest way to reliably link against [`devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.2.1`](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh/devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)? I am using CMake 3 as the build system.

Comment: I am using CentOS 7 and I also installed devtoolset-7 and enabled it the same way as you mentioned.  I tried to compile the regex example in the regex link in your post and it works fine.  I tried ldd on my executable and it references to the original libstdc++ as well.  What error did you get?

Comment: @Hei compile != work fine. the original libstdc++ does not implement std::regex, it simply throws an exception or return false all the time.

Comment: The whole point of the devtoolset version of GCC is that the binary only depends on the original system libstdc++, but that doesn't mean that `<regex>` doesn't work. If you compile with the devtoolset gcc then you get working a `<regex>` (I just tested it, and it works). The fact it's linked to the old `libstdc++.so` doesn't matter.