# std::regex_search not working for me

Tags: c++, regex, windows, codeblocks

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "hello";
    regex e (".*");
    cout << boolalpha << regex_search(s,e) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I compile/run it, it prints `false`. I have also tried to replace `regex_search(s,e)` with `regex_search(s.c_str(),e)`.
I have also changed `regex e (".*");` to:

```
1) regex e ("");
2) regex e ("hello");
3) regex e ("^.*$");
4) regex e ("^.+$");
5) regex e ("^hello$");
6) regex e (".ell.");
7) regex e ("ell");
```

And all of these printed `false` as well. However, when I use `regex_match()` instead of `regex_search()`, expressions number `0 (original), 2, 6` return `true`, which means `regex_match()` works just fine;

My OS is **Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]**
My IDE is **Code::Blocks 13.12**
The compile/link commands are (I removed path info in this post):

```
-------------- Build: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -Wall  -c main.cpp -o main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -o main.exe main.o
Output file is main.exe with size 1.62 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))


-------------- Run: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: main.exe
Executing: "cb_console_runner.exe" "main.exe"
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

The question is simple: What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Both functions evaluate to `true` for me. See [here](https://repl.it/repls/LargeFeminineArgali).

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with gcc-4.8: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7BbVpktH3MPZ0Idc . It works on all the newer versions I tried, though

Comment: I know gcc had broken regex support for a while after it was introduced. (see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions)

Comment: Your answer is useful and I appreciate that you came back to update your question. Unfortunately, putting an answer in your question "hides" it... this question will appear to be unanswered as far as indexing and searching goes. The best solution would obviously be to add an answer to your question, but since it was closed as a duplicate, the next-best solution is to add an answer to the duplicate question. Your answer will be more visible to others looking for a solution, and may end up earning you more reputation (if you care about such things)