# Why does regex work well in java, but does not work in c++?

Tags: java, c++, regex

using c++

```
    std::regex reg("[\\s\\S]*abc[\\s\\S]*:(\\S+)");
    std::string src = "    abc-def gg, :OK";
    std::smatch match;
    bool flag = std::regex_search(src, match, reg);
    // flag is false
```

using java

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\S]*abc[\\s\\S]*:(\\S+)");
        String src = "    abc-def gg, :OK";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(src);
        int num = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
                num++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);  num is 1 ,work well
```

In the above two code examples, The C++ code does not output the correct result, but the java code creates the correct result. Why is this happening, where is the problem?

Comment: `flag=1`, see [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/6sGV7J)

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `\\s` means 's' character. Did you mean that or a whitespace character?

Comment: Also, see [Is gcc 4.8 or earlier buggy about regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/3832970) What is your GCC version? Or, what library are you using? Are you on  Mac?

Comment: Side note: instead of the loop why not just `num = m.groupCount();`?

Comment: Actually, all you need in Java is `System.out.println(m.find());` or `if (m.find()) num = 1;` since you are just checking for a match.

Comment: @Thomas: Precisely `num += m.groupCount();` in case while executes multiple times.

Comment: look follow image link https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=280280d3af2cfd8f6030c92942d44695&type=note

http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=4c8f320678417df5ea6bf04594882493

Comment: Why don't you say us the compiler version? It's probably the reason for your problem. Your links are blocked for me.

Comment: g++ -vApple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)

Comment: how make it working in MAC OS,pls ?

Comment: Offtopic: `\\s` and `\\S` are [complementary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) – so why not replace `[\\s\\S]` with just `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Your example does not work on Mac OS.  I run into the same problem if I run it on a Mac.

Your final comment asked "how make it working in MAC OS,pls", which I am guessing is asking for the code to make this work on a Mac rather than asking why two regex implementations produce different results.  That is a much easier solution:

This works on my mac:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//  std::regex reg("[\\s\\S]*abc[\\s\\S]*:(\\S+)");
  std::regex reg("[\\s\\S]*abc.*:(\\S+)");
  std::string src = "    abc-def gg, :OK";
  std::smatch match;
  bool flag = std::regex_search(src, match, reg);
  std::cout << flag;
  return 0;
}
```

The same expression that works on regex101.com, does not work on the Mac (llvm).  It seems that the [\s\S] does not work well using Mac's regex library, but that can be solved by replacing the [\s\S] with `.*`.

In response to a further query to isolate the 'OK' portion of the string, that is done using groups.  The group[0] is always the entire match.  group[1] is the next portion appears between parentheses `(...)`

This code illustrates how to extract the two groups.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string GetMatch() {
  //  std::regex reg("[\\s\\S]*abc[\\s\\S]*:(\\S+)");
  std::regex reg("[\\s\\S]*abc.*:(\\S+)");
  std::string src = "    abc-def gg, :OK";
  std::smatch matches;
  bool flag = std::regex_search(src, matches, reg);
  std::cout << flag;

  for(size_t i=0; i<matches.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "MATCH: " << matches[i] << endl;
  }

  return matches[1];
}

int main() {
  std::string result = GetMatch();

//  match
  cout << "The result is " << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this work for flag is true,but I want to get  "OK"  string,  could you help me

Comment: how to get "OK" string  by regex ,pls help me

Comment: See additional code at end of answer which shows how to extract the 'OK'.