# C++11 regex doesn't match the test string

Tags: c++

I want to match this string like this:**Micron_5200_MTFDDAK3T8TDC**

I use a regular expression:**(Micron_5200_)?MTFDDAK(480|960|1T9|3T8|7T6)TD(C|D|N)**

Then I try it with C++:

```
string str="Micron_5200_MTFDDAK3T8TDC";
string pattern="(Micron_5200_)?MTFDDAK(480|960|1T9|3T8|7T6)TD(C|D|N)";
regex reg(pattern,regex_constants::extended);
cout << regex_match(str, reg) << endl;
```

I compile it on centos7.6 x64 using GCC 4.8.5 with -std=c++11 flag. But I always get No matches found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Works for me](https://ideone.com/pzFRnk)

Comment: Unfortunately, rather than just omitting a regex implementation gcc 4.8 had one that didn't work

Comment: You should update your compiler to GCC 4.9 to fix that, or use Boost Regex.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665408/8298564