# Seg fault when app & shared lib built with -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, libstdc++

If I build a C++ app with `-static-libstdc++` which loads a shared lib (via dlopen) which was also built with `-static-libstdc++`, then the app seg faults during dlopen.

BUT--this only happens in some setups:

- GCC 4.7.4, 32-bit:  pass
- GCC 4.8.3, 32-bit:  pass
- GCC 4.8.4, 64-bit:  pass
- GCC 4.9.2, 64-bit:  pass
- GCC 4.9.3, 32-bit:  FAIL (unless `RTLD_DEEPBIND` is specified)
- GCC 4.9.3, 64-bit:  pass

## Findings:

- If `-static-libstdc++` is not used when building for either the shared lib or the app, it works.
- If (`RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND`) is passed to dlopen, it works.  So I suspect the problem is related to symbol confusion/duplication between the app & .so.
- Interestingly, if I have the code load the .so first with (`RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND`), and then close it and re-load with only `RTLD_LAZY`, it also works.

## Repro Steps

### Code:

#### functions.cpp

```
extern "C"
{

  int ExportedFunction1()
  {
    std::cout << "\n---\n" << __FUNCTION__ << "\n---\n" << std::endl;
    return(0);
  }

}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  void * ph(NULL);

  if(argc == 2 && argv[1][0] == '1')
  {
     std::cout << "Calling dlopen with flags RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND..." << std::flush;
     ph = dlopen("./libfunctions.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
     std::cout << "done.  Result: " << ph << std::endl;
     if(ph)
        dlclose(ph);
  }

  std::cout << "Calling dlopen with flags RTLD_LAZY..." << std::flush;
  ph = dlopen("./libfunctions.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  std::cout << "done.  Result: " << ph << std::endl;
  if(ph)
       dlclose(ph);

  return 0;
}
```

### Build

```
$ g++ -m32 -g -fPIC -c functions.cpp -o functions.o
$ g++ -m32 -g -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libfunctions.so -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ functions.o -o libfunctions.so
$ g++ -m32 -g -fPIC -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ main.cpp -l dl -o main
```

### Run

```
$ ./main 
Calling dlopen with flags RTLD_LAZY...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

### Backtrace

```
$ gdb -c ./core ./main
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./main...done.
[New LWP 19846]

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-gate.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Core was generated by `./main'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  __atomic_add_single (__val=1, __mem=0x0)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:74
74    { *__mem += __val; }
(gdb) bt
#0  __atomic_add_single (__val=1, __mem=0x0)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:74
#1  __atomic_add_dispatch (__val=1, __mem=0x0)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/atomicity.h:98
#2  _M_add_reference (this=0x0)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/locale_classes.h:510
#3  std::locale::locale (this=0xb74f7ffc <__gnu_internal::buf_cout_sync+28>)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/locale_init.cc:223
#4  0xb746f559 in basic_streambuf (this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:466
#5  stdio_sync_filebuf (__f=0xb76a2a20 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, this=<optimized out>)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/build/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h:77
#6  std::ios_base::Init::Init (this=0xb74f7a01 <std::__ioinit>)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/gcc/gcc-4.9.3/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/ios_init.cc:85
#7  0xb7469419 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535)
    at /home/test/dev/3rdParty/build_toolchain/include/c++/4.9.3/iostream:74
#8  0xb7469456 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_functions.cpp(void) () at functions.cpp:12
#9  0xb772c25e in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#10 0xb772c35a in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#11 0xb7730622 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#12 0xb772c117 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#13 0xb772fdf4 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#14 0xb76edcae in ?? () from /lib/libdl.so.2
#15 0xb772c117 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#16 0xb76ee3b6 in ?? () from /lib/libdl.so.2
#17 0xb76edd61 in dlopen () from /lib/libdl.so.2
#18 0x0804e102 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfadc254) at main.cpp:18
```

It's odd to me that this only seems to fail in some versions of GCC, and only for 32-bit.  I have not tried GCC 5 yet.

I appreciate thoughts/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If -static-libstdc++ is not used when building for either the shared lib or the app, it works.

In general, you should *either* avoid using `-static-libstdc++`, *or* hide all of its symbols to avoid such problems.

> So I suspect the problem is related to symbol confusion/duplication between the app & .so.

Correct. In particular, the problem is that some symbols are duplicated, while others are not. We've had to [disable](https://cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/2011-10/msg00073.html) `STB_GNU_UNIQUE` symbols for that reason.

> if I have the code load the .so first with (RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_DEEPBIND), and then close it and re-load with only RTLD_LAZY, it also works.

That's because `dlclose` doesn't actually unload the library if you used it. From `man dlclose`:

```
The function dlclose() decrements the reference count on the dynamic
library handle handle.  If the reference count drops to zero and no
other loaded libraries use symbols in it, then the dynamic library
is unloaded.
```

You should be able to verify that this is the case by stopping the program in GDB after `dlclose` and looking at its `/proc/$PID/maps` -- it's very likely that you'll find that `libfunctions.so` is still present in memory.

Comment: All good information.  Some follow-up questions:  (1) Given this is a problem with duplication symbols, why does it work fine with some versions of GCC and the same version of GCC but with a 64-bit build?;  (2) Since the sample program doesn't actually do anything with the loaded library (simply calls dlopen and then dlclose), I wonder why it wouldn't get unloaded; (3) Is there a straightforward way to hide all of libstdc++'s symbols?