# hiding selected symbols in static library using wildcards on MAC OSX

Tags: ios, macos, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

is there any method to hide/strip symbols using wildcards in MAC OSX. My usecase is to use this method in makefile for building a library for iOS.

1. `strip -x` command strips all the symbols from the library. But I want to expose few   symbols using wildcard.
   2.Iin makefile using flag of `fvisibility=hidden` has no control for wildcards.

I found this method which uses ruby. I dont know how to use it for wildcard though. [Hiding the symbols of a static library in a dynamic library in MAC OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732979/hiding-the-symbols-of-a-static-library-in-a-dynamic-library-in-mac-os-x)